# Binding an Angular boolean to a Bootstrap Radio Button Group

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a model like this:

```
$scope.user = { is_active: true }
```

I'm currently displaying that in my template like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <!-- ... -->
    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Is Active</label>

       <div class="btn-group col-sm-5" data-toggle="buttons">
           <label class="btn btn-default">
               <input type="radio" ng-selected="{{ user.is_active }}" name="is_active">
               Active
           </label>
           <label class="btn btn-default">
               <input type="radio" ng-selected="{{ user.is_active }}" name="is_active">
               Inactive
           </label>
       </div>
</form>
```

This looks like this in practice:

[image]

How can I bind the value of `{{ user.is_active }}` to this button group in Bootstrap? I'd  like the correct button to be depressed based on what's selected in the model.

Comment: problem lies with running code that manipulates the DOM before angular does. If you remove boostrap script it works fine. Libraries that self intialize DOM manipulation really shouldn't be run on top of angular, rather run through directives within angular so angular can do the manipulation first. Opposite can mean loss of functionality/data binding if an element gets replaced without using `$compile`

Comment: If that's the case, how could I write a directive for this?

Comment: for the buttons they work without script as far as I can tell just by using `ng-class`  http://jsfiddle.net/YLKFk/4/  Note I removed bootstrap.js from `external resources`

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to look at the buttons in [Angular's bootstrap ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)- these are designed to work cleanly with Angular and so they use `ngModel` directly.

If you go this route you'll need to use `ngModel` by adding it to your buttons like this:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="user.is_active" name="is_active">
```

Sticking with the default Twitter Bootstrap- it uses the class `active` to define which label is active.  To set this you can use `ngClass`.  For instance on the label you want active when `is_active` is true you'll want this:

```
ng-class="{active:user.is_active==true}
```

And to control the value you'll need to use 'ngClick' on the label to toggle the value.

```
<label class="btn btn-default"  ng-class="{active:user.is_active==true}" ng-click="setActive(true)">
    <input type="radio">
        Active
</label>
<label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="{active:user.is_active==false}" ng-click="setActive(false)">
     <input type="radio">
         Inactive
 </label>
```

And the new function:

```
$scope.setActive = function(val) {
    $scope.user.is_active= val;
};
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YLKFk/4/)

Comment: @Rob I just updated the fiddle with twitter bootstrap and it works- could you post a demo of the problem you're seeing?

Comment: Yeah, I don't see any Bootstrap styling in your fiddle.

Comment: Here's my update, which isn't working but has jQuery, Angular, and Bootstrap properly included:  http://jsfiddle.net/YLKFk/2/

Comment: I see you added the url to the css section, but the styles are not applied. The styling should look similar to the Naftuli original post.

Comment: Interesting...  Looks like bootstrap needs it's own `active` class set.  I updated the answer

Comment: It's looking great, but doesn't seem to be updating the model (in your example, the value doesn't change when interacting with the buttons). Not sure why this is, I'm tinkering around with it myself.

Comment: It's definitely easier using the Angular bootstrap version.  If you don't then it seems you need to use `ngClick` to manually change the model variable.  Updated.